# sample Hello World ILOG Jrule?

Tags: java, ilog

I am new in business rules. I want to do some samples related to ILOG JRules BRMS. I have installed execution server and team server. Now how to get start in ILOG JRules ?

Any best blog/book where I can learn how to make rules ? I need hello World application.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to get all the informations related ILOG JRules BRMS is in this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ilog.jrules.doc/html/api/html/ilog/rules/factory/package-summary.html)

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451805/working-with-ibm-rule-engine) i have explained the steps you need to follow in order to write a simple business rule.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I need a sample projects / tutorials. Isn't there any blog or website where I can find alot of samples and materials to get expert in ILOG JRULES ?

Comment: Any standard installation of ILOG would have sample application to try all the features of ILOG.Typically there will be a miniloan application readily available to try. If you are using ILOG 7.1.1 then the sample application would under the folder C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphereILOGJRules711\gettingstarted

Comment: I have done that sample.. I want more material so I am capable of understand better ILOG Jrules and can practice more about that tool. Any other sample/material/tutorial will highly be appreciated.